# Updating Entity OneToMany relationship by passing arraycollection

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

Im trying to change an old arraycolection of $linhas for a new one by using the method 
setLinhas(Arraycollection $linhas) 
but what happens when it does the changes is that internally he creates a new object with the new lines and dont update the old object with the new lines. It creates a new instance with the same values as the old object. It was suppose to update the same object and not create a new one!

Entity's Property :

```
/**
 * @var ArrayCollection
 *
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\LinhasPrecos", mappedBy="preco",orphanRemoval=true,cascade={"persist","merge"})
 */
protected $linhas;

 /**
 * @param $linhas
 */
public function setLinhas($linhas)
{
    $this->linhas = new ArrayCollection($linhas);
}
```

In the service:

```
$oldObject->setLinhas($newObectWithNewLinhas->getLinhas());
$this->em->persist($oldObject);
```

but if I do the change manually it will work:

```
$oldLinhas = $oldObject->getLinhas()->getValues();

                        foreach($oldLinhas as $oldLinha)
                        {
                            $oldObject->removeLinha($oldLinha);
                        }

                        $linhaToCopy = $newObectWithNewLinhas->getLinhas()->getValues();

                        foreach($linhasCopyNew as $linhaCopyNew)
                        {
                            $oldObject->addLinha($linhaCopyNew);
                        }
```

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it wrong!

use this constructor and setter instead:

**Preco**

```
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Preco
{
    //...

    /**
     * @var Collection
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\LinhasPrecos", mappedBy="preco", orphanRemoval=true, cascade={"persist","merge"})
     */
    protected $linhas;

    //...

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->linhas = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function setLinhas($linhas)
    {
        $this->linhas = $linhas;
    }
}
```

**Notice**

- You should pass a doctrine collection into `setLinhas`.
- This way you are totally replacing an old collection, with the new collection (and not adding an element to the old collection).

Comment: The problem keeps, when I pass an new doctrine collection , it persist into a new object in db ( a new Preco)  instead of updating the existing one.

Comment: As I told, you asked for such a thing. Are you after a solution which adds an element to the old collection?!

Comment: Noo, I was trying to replace a complete old colection for a new one collection with new elements that dont know his owning side . I thought that this replace would be trivial by setting the $linhas property in the owning side Enitty (Preco).  But I have conscience that the lines from the new Array Collection dont know this price yet! although i thought this was done behind the curtains... did I explained well to you?

Comment: please edit your question and add an example to tell what do you exactly want